# Get element other web page using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to update 2 tables. Each table on an other web page. I'm using javascript to delete the object from the database and to delete the row from the 2 tables. But javascript can only delete the row from the table that is from that document.

Simply said: I can't get the table element from the other web page. After searching a while i found that i have to do it with jQuery/Ajax but i can't fix it. Here's part op my code:

```
function deleteItem(action,cdplayer,index){
    //using ajax to delete the object from database
    var information = "action=" + encodeURIComponent(action) + "&cdplayer=" +    encodeURIComponent(cdplayer);
    xHRObject.open("POST", "StockServlet", true);
    xHRObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xHRObject.send(information);

    //deleting the row from the table of that document
    var table = document.getElementById("tableAdmin");
    table.deleteRow(index); 

    //here i have to delete the table from the other document 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by other page? Is it a page that is not yet loaded in the browser window? If so, you can't manipulate it using client JS. You have one document element.

Comment: Are you saying you want to update data in a client browser using a "push" from the server?